# Most efficient way to calculate angle between two line-segments that do not necessarily touch each other

Tags: c#, 2d, geometry, angles

Although I found answers on calculating angles from vectors, I didn't find a specific way to calculate angles between line-segments that do not necessarily touch each other (I say "not necessarily because I will apply to different cases).

See the figure below:

[image]

Consider that I know the 2D position of all 4 red points. I am using C# here. What would be the cheapest way of calculating the angles formed by line-segments that do not touch each other, such like the ones above?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the angle between two lines that do touch each other? Why would this be any different?

Comment: Isn't it the angle between the vectors you want here? Whether the segments touch or not you can consider the angle between two infinite rays which is simply the dot product of the two vectors

Comment: @Steven so, if the points are named A, B, C and D, the angle would be equal Dot( A-B , C-D)? The subtraction is for getting the vectors from the points (should I take the absolute values to get rid of the sign?)

Comment: @congusbongus I don't know an efficient way (without trigonometry expensive stuff). But also, here I don't know the lines only the two vertices that are the start and end of the segments.

Comment: No don't get rid of the sign. Have a look here:http://m.intmath.com/vectors/5-dot-product-vectors-2-dimensions.php

Comment: @Steven I see what you mean. So the angle equals arccos[Dot( A-B , C-D)/abs(A-B)*abs(C-D)]. Is that right? Anyway, regarding computational complexity, I thought it would be possible to do avoid divisions or expensive trigonometry, but it's seems that it might be impossible.

Comment: Not sure what you intend to have when you say don't touch each other. It may be not that easy, as the dot product considers the non-touch case.Here it might depend on your chosen circle radius and circle center. Consider the case where the segment <CD> is parallel to <AB> but still not touching each other as in your illustration; then we would have a degree less than 180 degree due to the gap between them. Also, if the circle is small enough, it will just go round to 180 degrees. Is that what you want to calculate or are you happy with the angle between vectors case?

Comment: Basically, what you want is the regular two-point-form of a line equation, and once you have those two lines, you can transform them to calculate the angle between those lines. Unless, as @Majte says, you actually want what you drew above, which seems like the intersection points of a circle segment with the two lines, and then the angle of that circle segment. But then we'd need to know where you want the circle's center to be. What are you using this for?

Comment: @Majte at first I was looking for something a bit fancier, similar to what you had understood. But it turns out that simple angle between the infinite lines of these segments might can be enough. The only problem is that arccos, with dot product and division is still quite an expensive solution. I am playing with it to see what I can do here

Comment: There are tricks. If those walls are fixed, preprocess all calculations in the game initialization stage. Otherwise, calculate those angles once every 10 frames or only those angles within a certain distance to the player that are relevant.

Comment: Also what IS the meaning of expensive during runtime? I have 200000 arccos operations and possibly a few millions divisions per gameloop and if I uncap my framerate I end up with 131 frames compared to 135 frames per second without any calculations. Hence, I didn't bother yet to optimise my code as long as it is over 60 fps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `s1` and `s2` the segments, so you can calculate the angle of each using `atan2(s.p1.y-s.p2.y,s.p1.x-s.p2.x)` where `p1` and `p2` are the two points defining s;

```
double theta1 = Math.atan2(s1.p1.y-s1.p2.y,s1.p1.x-s1.p2.x);
double theta2 = Math.atan2(s2.p1.y-s2.p2.y,s2.p1.x-s2.p2.x);
```

Taking the absolute value of the difference, you get the angle between the segments:

```
double diff = Math.abs(theta1-theta2);
```

And finally, you can use the minor angle:

```
double angle=min(diff,Math.abs(180-diff));
```

Comment: Note that atan2 will return radians, but the last step is working with degrees. Use
`double diff = Math.abs(theta1-theta2) * 180 / Math.PI;`